# What is a bipartite quantum state?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement

I'm very confused for the definition [bipartite quantum states](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/bipartite-states-and-schmidt-decomposition). If it's just quantum states defined in $H_1 \otimes H_2$, then if $H_1$ and $H_2$ both are just 1 qubit system, then the bipartite quantum states on $H_1 \otimes H_2$ is just any 2 qubit states? If so, 5-partite quantum states on $H_1 \otimes H_2 \otimes ... \otimes H_5$ where $H_i$s are just 1 qubit systems mean any 5 qubit states?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a bipartite quantum system is simply one where there's a division between two parts of the system (e.g. two qubits, but need not be limited to a single qubit in each partition).

The motivation for such a division is *usually* to have those two parts be distantly separated so that they cannot easily interact, and you care about the resources required to perform operations under that distant separation restriction.